# Change Stack Exchange Password

Tags: support, password

I've been looking for over 10 minutes and I can't find where to do this. Where can I change my password?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below applies only to accounts using Stack Exchange as OpenID provider.

- Go to your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- Select `Edit Profile & Settings` tab
- In the left side sub menu select `My Logins`
- In the page select `change password` option
- Then enter the new password to update your password.

Screen shot for reference:

[image: Change password - screenshot]

Comment: What do you do when the "change password" link above isn't there? "remove" isn't there either. My login type is listed as "Other", not "Stack Exchange", I don't know what this means.