# Can't change account's password from "My Logins" page

Tags: bug, user-accounts, password, my-logins

Here is a weird thing, I simply can't [change my account's password](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285078/change-stack-exchange-password).

> - Go to your profile
> - Select Edit Profile & Settings tab
> - In the left side sub menu select My Logins
> - In the page select change password option
> - Then enter the new password to update your password.

At the profile page, "My Logins" section, when I click on "change password", it redirects me to the main site.

No error, no warning.

I can use "I forgot my password" to reset it but what's the problem here? Why is it not working?

I tried to change the password from different sites on the network but found the same result on all of them.

Comment: Looks like the option to change password from within that page is broken for a long time, it used to give error when trying, now it just do nothing which is even worse.

Comment: Related: [Can't change password](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316883/cant-change-password/346493). It never worked for me, I had to reset my password evey time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to this site:  https://openid.stackexchange.com/, and login to the account you want to change the password on.  At the top, you will see a "Change Password"  button.  Click and change.

**UPDATE:**

From the post [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018):

> Currently, https://openid.stackexchange.com/ is still on the internet, but we are in the process of completely removing it.

In light of this, I'm adding another way:

Just log out, and use the "Forgot Password" option shown here:

[image]

They will send you a recovery link.  This is the best way I know of if the My Logins way isn't working.